# Multiple or statements in a Javascript if statement

Tags: javascript

Okay, I'm fairly comfortable with basic If statements and know that if I want to say "When X is equal to 1 and Y is equal to 2 do whatever" I can write it as:

```
if ((X=="1") && (Y=="2")) {
```

But how do you write this:

If X is equal to 1 or 2 and Y is equal to 1 or 2, do whatever...

I tried the following, but none of these work.

```
if ((X=="1" || x=="2") && (Y=="2" || y=="1")) { 

if ((X=="1") || (x=="2") && (Y=="2") || (Y=="1")) {
```

Can someone explain to me what the format is?

Comment: I see `x` and `X` you do know that variable names are case sensitive in JS?

Comment: `if ((X=="1" || x=="2") && (Y=="2" || y=="1")) {  ` is correct, except that you misspelled the variable names.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I realised what I was doing wrong. In my actual code I was stupidly forgetting to redeclare the full statement.

I was essentially saying:

if ((X=="1" || "2") && (Y=="2" || "1")) {

My actual variables are a lot more complex than just X's and Y's, so  wasn't as obvious

Comment: @user2562275 please delete your question - it won't help anyone else if they find it.

Comment: if( {1:1,2:1}[x] && {1:1,2:1}[y] ) {

Comment: @dandavis interesting way, could be useful! I don't find link to explain usage or limitation about array checking as you are using in your condition. Do you?

Comment: @sdespont: i use the pattern a lot when i need a one-of-the-above comparison. i don't know if anyone else does it, but it works like a charm and by naming the array you can re-use the logic in different places.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript, like most languages, is case sensitive.

```
if ((X == "1" || X == "2") && (Y == "2" || Y == "1")) {
```

Answer (score 2):

`if ((X=="1" || x=="2") && (Y=="2" || y=="1")) {` is fine except that `X` and `x` are different variables (as are `Y` and `y`).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to use lower case and upper case X's and Y's. Basically, there are only two variables - X & Y.

Answer (score 1):

Check your cases, `x` is different from `X`.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the names of your variables (they are case-sensitive):

**x** is not the same as **X**
**y** is not the same as **Y**

this should work:

```
if ((X=="1" || X=="2") && (Y=="1" || Y=="2")) {
```